# How would you create unit tests for a data intensive application which could run an endless amount of db queries?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I am working on a reporting application (in PHP). This app has a huge amount of different filters, granulations, etc. in the UI and based on those filters etc, the backend constructs a massive query to pull hundreds of rows of data from the db.

How is it possible to write unit tests for something like this?

Lets say I create a test db with some known data. Would I create a bunch of tests where I compare the returned data set (for whatever filter settings) against hardcoded SQL queries in the tests?

Would this mean that for any schema change, I have to go back and change every single SQL query in the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing isn't testing in way that uses real code or data, you mock everything you work with.  You wouldn't test it in the way you are describing, nor need to.  You aren't testing what data you get, only that the data you feed it, after the method processes it, is what you expect or similar.

For example, if you have a method that returns data retrieved from a database, the database has nothing to do with your test.  You are testing just that method and the logic there within; what methods you may call within it, expectations as to what you expect those methods within it to do (like return a generic representation of a value you can do an assertion on) etc, and everything outside of that method is mocked (i.e. a generic representation).

In a simple example, if you created one method that is a setter of something, and a one method used as a getter of that something, then you will write a test that says when I use the setter the getter will return the same value.... boom, both methods are tested.

This is the reason why you hear about TDD (test driven development), which may feel counter intuitive at first, but it forces a developer to put together the pieces required to write testable code, which ultimately leads to code that's better.  Yes, you can write code that functions perfectly, but it's not necessarily testable (or nearly impossible to), and that's an indicator that it's entirely too coupled, meaning it's not that reusable.  For example, instead of creating a method that returns the number of apples, you could create a method that injects the object type so no matter what type of fruit you are using in that part of the project, it could return you a count (oranges, apples, pears, or not even fruit at all).  That makes that method reusable, and also means you won't be writing methods for each type of fruit either (so you write less code).

Anyway, provide an example of your code, and your test, to see what the issue is.